# Unity - export package - but on import, scene and folder structure are different (screenshots)

Tags: unity, import, export

I export a package and shows me all the files I am exporting.

When I go to import this package, one of the files is renamed and placed in a folder that no longer exists.

Can anyone explain what is happening here and how I can fix it?

Here is the image of me exporting, including the assets folder in the screenshot.

[image: export image]

Then I start a new project, and I try to import that package. But a filename has changed itself, and there is a folder there that I did not export, I actually purposely deleted it and it exported anyway:

[image: import image]

Comment: Additional note, when I open the project I originally exported from, it has the folder structure and file names I expect, unlike the package that it keeps exporting.

Comment: it's a default folder with Samplescene. it will create automatically once you create new project. don't worry about that. it wont affect your project.

Comment: @ManojBalajiM did you notice i lost a scene though? it is (based on other tests i have done besides the one shown in the screenshot) taking scn_E09.unity and moving it and renaming it on its own.

Comment: this kind of problems may occur in unity sometimes. update your unity and do export. maybe it's help